# ExoPlayer Which MediaSource to Use based on URL

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have a set of audio-only URLs that I want to put into `ExoPlayer` - some need `HlsMediaSource`, and some need `ExtractorMediaSource`.

Without knowing ahead of time which URLs need which MediaSource, is there a way to determine which to construct the source with?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class that implements `MediaSource` and provide `HlsMediaSource` and `ExtractorMediaSource` as constructor arguments.
Then in `MediaSource.open` method you can get `DataSpec` and check URL (according your business logic) and choose required data source and delegate open method. You also should implement `read` and `close` methods, so you need some field with current data source opened.